# Android error, cannot bind argument because index is out of range

Tags: android

I have given a statement in DBAdapter class as follows

```
String sql="SELECT A.Acc_No,A.Cust_Name, T.Trans_Amnt FROM TransactionTable "
        + "T LEFT JOIN AccMaster A on A.Acc_ID = T.Acc_ID "
        + "WHERE T.Trans_Date ='"+ date +"' AND T.Trans_Type='debit' ORDER BY  T.Entry_Time asc";

return db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{KEY_ACCNO,KEY_ACCCUSTNAME,KEY_TRANSAMOUNT});
```

My activity calling is given below

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.gettranscation();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                DisplayDetails(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("Retrive Error ", " "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void DisplayDetails(Cursor c) {
    Log.e("",
          "KEY_ACCID Id : " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "KEY_TRANSDATE :"
                            + c.getString(1) + "\n" + "KEY_TRANSTYPE : " + c.getString(2));
}

    });
```

But I am getting this error :

> Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range. The
>   statement has 0 parameters.

What is the error in my code ??

Comment: Please provide `gettranscation` code from your db class. it seems your problem is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....

```
String sql = "SELECT A.Acc_No,A.Cust_Name, T.Trans_Amnt 
FROM TransactionTable T 
LEFT JOIN AccMaster A on A.Acc_ID = T.Acc_ID 
WHERE T.Trans_Date =? AND T.Trans_Type=? 
ORDER BY T.Entry_Time asc";


Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"18-08-2014", "debit"});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You're not putting well "SelectionArgs". To put it well in the query you have to add the character "?" where you want this argument.

The official documentation [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal))

Example:

```
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id = ?";
 db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{idUser});
```

**EDIT**

You aren't using never SelectionArgs because you are binding params directly.

Try this.

```
return db.rawQuery(sql,null);
```

Comment: Tanx TeRRo...it helped.